# How do i overwrite a single permission in a channel for '@everyone'

Tags: discord.py

Here is my code. It sets all other permissions to default and changes send messages to false.

```
    @client.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
    async def lock(ctx):
            await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, send_messages=False)
            await ctx.send('Channel locked.')
    @lock.error
    async def lock_error(ctx, error):
            if isinstance(error,commands.CheckFailure):
                    await ctx.send('You do not have permission to use this command!')
```

Comment: Your code seems to work perfectly well, what issue are you experiencing with it? If users are still able to talk after the channel has been locked, I recommend looking to see if they have any roles that will override that permission to explicitly send messages.

Comment: when unlocking the channel(same code but with send_messages=True), it would set that permission to yes and also have all other permissions to '/' meaning @everyone could see a locked chat

Comment: Ahh right, so you'd like to keep all other permissions the same as to what they were before and only change one permission, but instead when changing the one permission they all change to '/'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your comment correctly, this code should keep all other permissions the same, and only change the ones you explicitly tell it to:

```py
    @client.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
    async def lock(ctx):
            overwrite = ctx.channel.overwrites_for(ctx.guild.default_role)
            overwrite.send_messages = False
            await ctx.channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, overwrite=overwrite)
            await ctx.send('Channel locked.')
    @lock.error
    async def lock_error(ctx, error):
            if isinstance(error,commands.CheckFailure):
                    await ctx.send('You do not have permission to use this command!')
```

---

**References:**

- [`TextChannel.overwrites_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.overwrites_for)
- [`discord.PermissionOverwrite()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.PermissionOverwrite)
- [`TextChannel.set_permissions()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.set_permissions)

Comment: Was really my only issue, now got to work on setting timed messages up :)